# Вопросы по MySQL кэшированию

Tags: mysql, sql

Неделю назад загрузил базу данных для SuiteCRM. Включил кэширование.
Где то через сутки страницы начались открываться за секунду. Результат ранее до 4 секунд на формирование страницы.
Сегодня удалил базы данных и залил заново. Опять страница начала открываться за 3 секунды с включенным кэшом. 
Пробовал перезагружать одну и ту же страницу, но время загрузки не сокращалось.
Не могу понять почему неделю назад через сутки после включения кэширования страница начала открываться за секунду, при том что с базой данных практически никто не работал.

Comment: А что вы имеете ввиду под кешированием. Это кеширование чего ? средство самого MySQL или вашей CRM

Comment: query_cache_type = ON
query_cache_limit = 499M
query_cache_size = 499M

Comment: кеши мало что решат, если запросы в БД например идут полным перебором таблицы потому что не хватает каких то индексов. оптимизацию работы с БД надо начинать с оптимизации запросов. надо смотреть планы выполнения всех запросов в системе. и подстраивать индексы под запросы и/или менять сами запросы.

Comment: Да но у меня страница до перезаливки юазы данных, формировалась за секунду

Comment: ну может при перезаливке какие нибудь индексы не создались. хотя это конечно странно. и если до этого данные просто постепенно писались, то данные на диске могли быть сильно дефрагментированы, но так, что часто выбираемые вместе данные лежали рядом. А перезаливка расположила таблицы строго по очереди и теперь головкам бегать от записи одной таблицы до зависимых записей других таблиц приходится гораздо дальше

Comment: Смотрел PHPMyAdmin-ом дефрагментации нет. База данных размером 200 мегабайт, т.е. маленькая

Comment: @victor-kurenkov а какой размер самих таблиц, сколько строчек и как идет выборка? странно, что вообще запрос даже секунду отрабатывает. у вас вся база должна сидеть в оперативке, при правильной настройке индексов и размера кэшей все должно отрабатывать гораздо быстрее.

Comment: Victor Kurenkov посмотрите через профайлер (например, xdebug) все запросы, которые делает страница в базу, какие наиболее тяжелые? обычно на практике 2-3 тяжелых запроса и составляют 90% времени обращения к базе (не считая подключения). через профайлер сразу будет понятно, сидит запрос в кэше или идет обращение к базе (там время в разы отличается, особенно для большой базы).

Comment: Да! Есть один запрос, долгий запрос. А как через профайлер посмотреть откуда запрос берёт информацию?

Answer (score 0):

А что там у вас за ПО еще стоит, есть memcache или какие-нибудь дополнительные системы кэширования в вашей CRM? Вы уверены, что дело именно в кэшировании MySQL, а не web-сервера или браузера?

Если говорить про сами кэши MySQL, то дело может быть в их разогреве. Надо смотреть какие именно данные там сидят. Может было так, что пока вы открывали страницы с одними данными, они сидели в кэше (поэтому все и работало быстро), а сейчас нужные данные либо быстро из него вымываются или вообще не попадают полностью в кэш.

Установите для начала систему мониторинга, посмотрите параметры и размер кэшей, а также как они себя ведут.

Посмотрите через профайлер (например, xdebug) все запросы, которые делает страница в базу, какие наиболее тяжелые? Обычно на практике 2-3 тяжелых запроса и составляют 90% времени обращения к базе (не считая подключения). Через профайлер сразу будет понятно, сидит запрос в кэше или идет обращение к базе (там время в разы отличается, особенно для большой базы).

Comment: query_cache_type = ON
query_cache_limit = 499M
query_cache_size = 499M

Comment: а какой тип таблиц? innodb или myisam?

Comment: У меня innodb. В прошлый раз только через сутки при полном молчании запросов из вне, страницы начали открываться за секунду

Comment: ну тогда вам нужно смотреть совсем не те кэши, пришлите значение innodb_buffer_pool_size

Comment: установите Munin или аналогичную систему мониторинга, подключите все плагины для InnoDB (mysql_innodb_*), а в особенности mysql_innodb_bpool. по крайней мере это даст хоть какое-то понимание, влияют ли кэши на производительность в вашем случае или нет.